# How to select range between Begin_date and End_date - mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, range

In this case i have "leave" table:

```
+--------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+-----------+
|ID_LEAVE|ID_WORKER| BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE              |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+------------+------------+
| 4      |   26    |2019-03-19 07:00:00  |2019-03-22 15:00:00    |  
+--------+---------+---------+----------------------+------------+
```

In wanna write mysql query which selects all in range between Begin Date and End date and then sum up. When i write like that:

```
SELECT *, 
time_format(SUM((datediff(END_DATE, BEGIN_DATE) + 1) * (time(END_DATE) - time(BEGIN_DATE))), '%H:%i:%s') AS 'LEAVE TIME' 
FROM leave 
WHERE (DATE(BEGIN_DATE) >= '2019-03-19' AND DATE(END_DATE) <='2019-03-22') 
GROUP BY ID_LEAVE;
```

Then shows like this:

```
    +--------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+------------------------+
    |ID_LEAVE|ID_WORKER| BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE              | LEAVE_TIME |
    +--------+---------+---------+---------+------------+--------------------+-----
    | 4      |   26    |2019-03-19 07:00:00  |2019-03-22 15:00:00    |  32:00:00  |
    +--------+---------+---------+----------------------+------------+-------------
```

But when i do like that:

```
SELECT *, 
time_format(SUM((datediff(END_DATE, BEGIN_DATE) + 1) * (time(END_DATE) - time(BEGIN_DATE))), '%H:%i:%s') AS 'LEAVE TIME' 
FROM leave 
WHERE (DATE(BEGIN_DATE) >= '2019-03-19' AND DATE(END_DATE) <='2019-03-21') 
GROUP BY ID_LEAVE;
```

It shows nothing.

I have a question: Is it possible to show all in (Begin_date and End_date) range? If yes to can someone please explain how to write it? Thanks for any answer.

Comment: I think you mean any active, and active and completed in the data range ie could start before start date and end before end date, could start before end data and end after end data etc. In which case you need to work out all the possible scenarios and code for them.

Comment: I want to see the result between '2019-03-21' And '2019-03-22' to show anything because it shows nothing. And you're right